# sort varchar column codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i first checked if there any same problems like mine i ddnt find anything. 
all are sorting alphanumeric column mixed with numeric data.

here is my problem. 
i have a table that contain column A datas like this.

> WRG-01 WRG-39 WRG-22 WRG-45 WRG-43

need to sort that as

> WRG-01 WRG-22 WRG-39 WRG-43 WRG-45

this is the code i using so far in codeigniter frame work

```
$data['products'] = $this->db->order_by('product_id', 'asc')->get('products');
```

in mysql i can use this query to get done my work

```
preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "",'product_id'), 'asc')
```

***How to apply it to my above codeigniter code?***

here is search funtion

```
public function search()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Search Product';
    $product_name       = $this->input->get('product_name');
    $product_id         = $this->input->get('product_id');
    $product_category   = $this->input->get('product_category');
    $secondCategory     = $this->input->get('secondCategory');
    $thirdCategory  = $this->input->get('thirdCategory');

$data['category'] = $this->db->order_by('id', 'asc')->get_where('categories', ['parent' => 0]);
if($product_category != '')
{
    $data['secondCategory'] = $this->db->get_where('categories', ['parent' => $product_category]);
}
if($secondCategory != '')
{
    $data['thirdCategory'] = $this->db->get_where('categories', ['parent' => $secondCategory]);
}


if($product_name != '')
    {
        $this->db->like('product_name', $product_name);
    }
    if($product_id != '')
    {
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
    }
    if($product_category != '')
    {
        $this->db->where('product_category', $product_category);
    }
    if($secondCategory != '')
    {
        $this->db->where('secondCategory', $secondCategory);
    }
    if($thirdCategory != '')
    {
        $this->db->where('thirdCategory', $thirdCategory);
    }



    $data['products'] = $this->db->order_by('product_id' 'asc')->get('products');


    theme('all_product', $data);

}
```

i can't use sql query here because products is result array from product table.

Comment: Have you tried $this->db->order_by(preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "",'product_id'), 'asc')->get('products');

Comment: @JasbirSinghSohanpal thanks. but i added full search function for your consideration.. can't use sql query directly there. because it's data array containg search result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MySQL `cast`

`cast(product_id as SIGNED)`

or

`cast(product_id as UNSIGNED)`

Try query like that :-

```
select * from products cast(product_id as UNSIGNED) ASC|DESC
```

Comment: i tried it working on sql query and give the correct result. but how to implement that on my code. i gave full search function there.

Comment: $query = $this->db->query("
select * from products cast(product_id as UNSIGNED) ASC
")

Comment: use custom query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435390/how-to-execute-my-sql-query-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ??==?? ORDER BY product_id ASC");
$result= $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

> as default data will sort by **Ascending Order**

---

This is in model. So if you pass it to controller it will return data as **Objective Array**.

So in controller you can access

```
$result = $this->model_name->method_for_above_code();
$name = $result[0]['name'];
$id = $result[0]['id'];
```

if in View

```
$result['this_for_view'] = $this->model_name->method_for_above_code();
foreach ($this_for_view as $new_item) {
    echo "Name is ".$new_item['name'];
    echo "ID is ".$new_item['id'];
}
```

Comment: thank you.  but there is another problem. products  is result set data array.

Comment: ya its objective array. You know how to access it??

Comment: @hasan Check **EDIT 01**