# Codeigniter - how to delete row on inner join?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables. 
[image: delete_on_join]

And I want to delete `pegawai` record using INNER JOIN, this works fine in MySQL.

```
DELETE p.* FROM pegawai p
INNER JOIN agama a ON p.agama_id = a.id
INNER JOIN jabatan j ON p.jabatan_id = j.id
WHERE a.id = 2 AND j.id = 5
```

But, how to use it on codeigniter? I can't find on query builder docs how to produce `DELETE p.* FROM pegawai p`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435390/how-to-execute-my-sql-query-in-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks, sir. But is it possible to combine regular query and query builder, just like `$this->db->query($SQL)` with `$this->db->where('a.id',2)`?

Comment: regular query does not work with `$this->db->where('a.id',2)` as i remember (have not used CI for long time). But do try the proposed answer i think it is exactly what you need.