# Mysql: Set particular value of column using update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-update

How to set particular value of column using update in mysql?

Following is my code:

```
update contact set admin_id = ' ' where admin_id like '%,519,%' and id='31'
```

[image]

I have a table having named `contact` and I have defined a column name `admin_id` as shown in the image. I have an id i.e. `,519,520,521` and now I want to delete only `519` from `admin_id` and want only `,520,521` inside the `admin_id` column.

What should be the query to achieve this?

Comment: use `replace` function

Comment: Are you sure you want to be storing comma separated values? This is notoriously bad design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work -

```
update contact 
set admin_id = replace(admin_id, '519,', '') 
where admin_id like '%,519,%' 
and id='31'
```

[replace()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php)

Comment: how to use this query in codeigniter model @Sougata Bose  $re = replace(admin_id,'$client_id,','');
      $data = array(
        'admin_id'=>$re
        );
      $where = "admin_id like '%$client_id%' and id = '$id'";
      $this->db->where($where);
       $this->db->update('contact',$data);

Comment: Not sure. But there must be some way to implement raw expression

Comment: okk but when I run this query it show me error and i.e. Call to undefined function replace()

Comment: THis should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435390/how-to-execute-my-sql-query-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 3):

You can use MySQL `REPLACE()` to achieve this

```
UPDATE contact SET admin_id = REPLACE(admin_id, ',519,', ',') 
WHERE admin_id LIKE '%,519,%' AND id='31'
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess something like this should work (but didn't test..)

```
UPDATE contact
SET admin_id = REPLACE(admin_id, '519', '')
WHERE admin_id like '%,519,%' and id='31'
```

you can find more here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html