# How to execute delete raw query in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have sql query for delete multiple record from database

```
$sql="delete from users where id IN(4,5,6..)";
```

How to run this query in codeigniter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute my SQL query in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435390/how-to-execute-my-sql-query-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 5):

Per the [documents](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html), you can use the query builder, or you can run a direct query on the database.

> The query() function returns a database result object when “read” type
>   queries are run, which you can use to show your results. When “write”
>   type queries are run it simply returns TRUE or FALSE depending on
>   success or failure. When retrieving data you will typically assign the
>   query to your own variable, like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('delete from users where id IN(4,5,6..)');
```

Or you can use the query builder [class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#deleting-data) which allows you to do the following:

```
$this->db->where_in('id', array(4,5,6));
$this->db->delete('users');
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in you model

```
function rowDelete($ids)
{
   $this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
   $this->db->delete('testimonials'); 
}
```

And call that in your controller

```
$this->your_model->rowDelete($ids) // $ids = array(4,5,6);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also execute query like this

```
$delete = "id IN('4','5','6')";
$this->db->where($delete);
$this->db->delete("user");
```

In this you can also execure your core query.