# How to convert sql query to codeigniter query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Can somebody help me convert this **Sql Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN customer_order co 
ON c.customer_number = co.customer_number 
AND co.order_status IN ('preparing', 'prepared')
WHERE c.customer_status='unpaid'
AND c.order_status = 'unserve'
AND co.cus_ord_no IS null
```

into **Codeigniter query** just like the image below for example

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute my SQL query in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435390/how-to-execute-my-sql-query-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When query statements do not have clauses that need to change conditionally then using `$this->db-query()` is the way to go.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer c LEFT JOIN customer_order co 
ON c.customer_number=co.customer_number AND co.order_status IN ('preparing', 'prepared')
WHERE c.customer_status='unpaid' AND c.order_status='unserve' AND co.cus_ord_no IS null";

$query = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
echo json_encode($query);
```

It might be wise to include a check on the return from `query()` though because if it fails (returns false) then the call to `result()` will throw an exception. One way that can be handled is like this.

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if($query !== FALSE) 
{
    echo json_encode($query->result());
    return;
}

echo json_encode([]); // respond with an empty array
```

Query Builder (QB) is a nice tool, but it is often overkill. It adds a lot of overhead to create a string that literally is passed to `$db->query()`. If you know the string and it doesn't need to be restructured for some reason you don't need QB.

QB is most useful when you want to make changes to your query statement conditionally. Sorting might be one possible case.

```
if($order === 'desc'){
   $this->db->order_by('somefield','DESC'); 
} else {
       $this->db->order_by('somefield','ASC'); 
}

$results = $this->db
    ->where('other_field', "Foo")
    ->get('some_table')
    ->result();
```

So if the value of `$order` is `'desc'` the query statement would be

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE other_field = 'Foo' ORDER BY somefield 'DESC'
```

But if you insist on using Query Builder I believe this your answer

```
$query = $this->db
    ->join('customer_order co', "c.customer_number = co.customer_number AND co.order_status IN ('preparing', 'prepared')", 'left')
    ->where('c.customer_status','unpaid')
    ->where('c.order_status','unserve')
    ->where('co.cus_ord_no IS NULL')
    ->get('customer c');

//another variation on how to check that the query worked
$result = $query ? $query->result() : [];
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
public function view_customers()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer c LEFT JOIN customer_order co ON c.customer_number = co.customer_number AND co.order_status IN ('preparing', 'prepared') WHERE c.customer_status='unpaid' AND c.order_status = 'unserve' AND co.cus_ord_no IS null";

    return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
}
```

You can use `row()` for one output to `object`, or `row_array()` if one output but `array`. `result()` is multiple `objects` and `result_array()` is multiple `arrays`.

My way do usually is like this:

Controller:

```
public function view()
{
    $this->load->model('My_Model');

   $data = new stdclass;
   $data->user_lists = $this->my_model->view_users(array('nationality'=>'AMERICAN'));
}
```

Model:

```
public function view_users($param = null) //no value passed
{
   $condition = '1';
   if (!empty($param)) { //Having this will trap if you input an array or not
     foreach ($param as $key=>$val) {
       $condition .= " AND {$key}='{$val}'"; //Use double quote so the data $key and $val will be read.
     }
   }

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE {$condition}"; //Use double quote so the data $condition will be read.
   // Final out is this "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1 AND nationality='AMERICAN'";

   return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
}
```